# need to implment paypal API

Tags: php, paypal

is there any API in paypal for receive fund form sender account using receiver account

means I have to implement withdraw functionality user can withdraw money form Merchant account

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, there's not much info on this issue. Have you tried asking their support? [Here is a similar question](https://paypal-community.com/t5/Merchant-services/Is-it-Possible-to-Withdraw-Money-from-Paypal-through-API/td-p/179852) and in the answer it's said that you need to contact support for enabling this feature

Comment: thanks for reply but I need to send money form Merchant account to user account but with user login means we have one button on our site like withdraw when user click on it he will enter his paypal email id and then he click on submit button one he click on submit using paypal API we have to transfer amount form site merchant account to this users account

Comment: As far as I know there are special API methods for this like DoDirectPayment - all of them are described here https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_api_reference